# how to solve this simple equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve a bigger problem however I am stuck at this step:

How can I solve:

$$
2^x - x = 5
$$

any hints/tips/steps please?

Comment: Trial and error? 1 doesn't work, 2 doesn't work, ... (If you plot $y=2^x$ and $y=5+x$ in the same diagram, you'll see that there are two solutions, but I don't think the second one has a simple closed form.)

Comment: Normally I might say something about Newton's method or about attractive fixed points.  But in this case the answer is staring you in the face.

Comment: One solution is "obvious". The other real solution needs the services of Lambert.

Comment: the second solution is somewhere between $-5$ and $-4$

Comment: $\approx -4.969$

Comment: Thanks, I know the answer is obvious in this case and can be found via trial and error. I was just wondering if there is a more concrete method that could be used for cases when the answer is not obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments there is an integer solution.  For the other solution is existence of a solution good enough?  You can use the Intermediate Value Theorem on the function $f(x)=2^x-x-5$.  It is negative at $x=0$ and positive at $x=-6$.  So, somewhere in between the IVT says there must be a $0$.  Or you can use Newton's method on $f$ to approximate the $0$ of $f$.